# POST to SharePoint Task List Results in Bad Request?

Tags: sharepoint-online, ajax, post

I am loading all my data with a GET to populate to a DataTable. When a row is selected and drawn to a new table, it deletes from the DataTable as well as the SharePoint list it came from. I am trying to then populate a new SharePoint list with the deleted row, using the rowNode to populate an item `data: JSON.stringify(item);` to post to the list. I have all of the fields correct, but I am getting a 400 error when trying to execute it? I have tried debugging and cannot figure it out, it tells me in the network tab that it failed to load response data?

Here is my code:
loading data to populate to the DataTable

```
function loadTasks() {
    var uri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('TestDynamicTaskList')/items?$expand=AssignedTo&$select=Title,Priority,ID,Status,StartDate,DueDate,PercentComplete,AssignedTo/Title,AssignedTo/Id";
    $.ajax({
        url: uri,
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.d != null && data.d != undefined && data.d.results.length > 0) {
                console.log(data);
                var table = $('#taskTable').DataTable();
                table.rows.add(data.d.results).draw();
            }
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert("Status: " + textStatus);
            alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

```
$('#taskTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
        } else {
            table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        }
    });

    $('#button').click(function() {
        var selRowData = table.row('.selected').data();
        table.row('.selected').remove().draw(false);
        console.log(selRowData.AssignedTo.results[0].Id);
        console.log(selRowData.Priority);
        console.log(selRowData.Title);
        console.log(selRowData.Status);
        console.log(selRowData.StartDate);
        console.log(selRowData.DueDate);
        console.log(selRowData.PercentComplete);
        var listItemID = selRowData.ID;

        var item = {
            "__metadata": { "type": "SP.Data.TestDynamicTaskList2ListItem" },
            "AssignedToId": {
                "results": [
                    selRowData.AssignedTo.results[0].Id
                ]
            },
            "Priority" : selRowData.Priority,
            "Title" : selRowData.Title,
            "Status" : selRowData.Status,
            "Start Date": selRowData.StartDate,
            "Due Date": selRowData.DueDate,
            "Percent Complete" : selRowData.PercentComplete
        };

        completedTaskTable
            .row.add(selRowData)
            .draw();
            deleteCertTask(listItemID);
            insertCompletedTask(item);
    });

    function deleteCertTask(listItemID){
    var url2 = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('TestDynamicTaskList')/items("+listItemID+")";
    $.ajax({
        url: url2,
        method: "DELETE",
        contentType: "application/json; odata=verbose",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "IF-MATCH": "*",
            "X-HTTP-Mthod": "DELETE",
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            alert("Item has been successfully deleted!");
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert("Status: " + textStatus);
            alert("Error :" + errorThrown);
        }
    });
    }

    function insertCompletedTask(item){
        $.ajax({
          url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('TestDynamicTaskList2')/items",
          method: "POST",
          credentials: 'include',
          data: JSON.stringify(item),
          headers: {
              Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose",
              "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
              "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
              "X-HTTP-Method": "POST",
          },
          success: function (data, status, xhr) {
              alert("New Form Item Created Successfully");
          },
          error: function (xhr, status, error) {
              alert(JSON.stringify(error));
              console.log(error);
          },
      });
    }
```

Everything works except for when insertCompletedTask(item); is executed. It even shows me what (item) is in the console and everything looks correct? In the local scope it shows the item and every column/piece of data associated with it is what it is supposed to be.

I get message: "textStatus is not defined" followed by Error 400

After it goes through the insertcompletedTask(item), it goes back up to deleteCertTask and error throws a readyState 4, error 200. But it still deletes the list item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a Tasks list, "Assigned To" is a multi user column.  For user fields, SharePoint exposes a "shorthand" way to get and set the field using only the user ID by adding a suffix "Id" to the name of the field, so in this case it would be "AssignedToId".

You're not seeing that "shorthand" because you are `$select`ing `AssignedTo/Title,AssignedTo/Id` and then `$expand`ing the Assigned To field, which causes the full expansion of the field and bypasses the "shorthand" version.

If the user column is a single user only, you can just assign the user ID directly to the shorthand version of the field name.  But Assigned To is multi-user, so even if you are only setting a single user, you have to set it using a `results` array.

So try setting up your JSON like this:

```
var item = {
    // ... etc...
    "AssignedToId": {
        "results": [
            selRowData.AssignedTo.results[0].Id
        ]
    }
    // ... etc...
}
```

Comment: I updated my question reflecting your answer, I am still getting a 400 Error

Comment: fixed it, it was how I had the keys set up in the item object

Comment: Dylan, if you have a chance can you please take a look. I `console.log(              selRowData.Author.Id)` and it is exactly what I expect it to be, but it will not allow me to post that value to a person or group column. https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/297516/workflow-email-to-a-name-string